# Automatically changing dictionary value in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using this method

```
def parse_on_save(self, response): 
    rows = response.xpath('//table[2]/tr')
    for row in rows: 
        id_val = row.xpath('td[1]/font/text()').extract_first() 
        yield { "id" : id_val
```

Getting value While scraping

```
{'Id': '0606130001'}
```

But when I try to store in csv file saving without 0

```
Id
606130001
```

But i need output:

```
Id
0606130001
```

Comment: How do you save it? It looks like you are casting it to an int at some point but should keep it as a string.

Comment: @Smviswa, could you please post the code you are using to write the `Id` to the `csv` file.

Comment: I used this code:  def parse_on_save(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//table[2]/tr')
        for row in rows:
            id_val = row.xpath('td[1]/font/text()').extract_first()
            yield {
                "id" : id_val
            }

Comment: If you are opening the output in Excel or similar software it most likely has to do with the number formatting. Try to open your CSV file with a text editor and check what value it shows.

Comment: Yes text editor working perfectly. But why not taking Excel

Comment: Excel automatically formats digits as numbers and removes the leading zeros. If you format a number in Excel as `'01`, it will format it as text, and leave the leading zeros. So you could try: `yield { "id": "'" + id_val}`